# Remove whitespace except non-breaking spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm using the following JS code to replace one or more consecutive whitespace characters with a single space character:

```
textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

I would like to modify the regex to ignore non-breaking spaces.

For example, this:

```
ABC   \u00a0\u00a0XYZ
```

Should result in this:

```
ABC \u00a0\u00a0XYZ
```

Comment: Do you mean to also replace the non-breaking spaces? If not, please clarify what you mean by 'skipping the non-breaking spaces'. Ideally give some examples.

Comment: The non-breaking spaces shouldn't be replaced

Comment: This has been discussed a lot of times. `/(?:(?!\u00A0)\s)+/g` or `/[^\S\u00A0]+/g` will do.

Comment: @ivan-pozdeev *Exclude characters from a character class doesn't say anything about handling Unicode characters, nor how to match "any whitespace character except a specific one".* - Of course not. It uses `\w` as an example **for the general case**. It's like me pointing you to a duplicate question which asks "what happens if I add 1 to a number" and the answer is "let's take 2, for example - the result is the next number to the right along the number line, i.e., 3". What you're saying is the equivalent of "but that answer doesn't help me as the number in my question is not 2". Seriously!?